# Ubuntu 16.04 boot up issue

Tags: 16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and recently my HP 255 laptop just hangs on the purple screen with the caps lock button light flickering.

I don't know if the below image of my Ubuntu boot-up issue will assist in my query, but that's what I get when selecting the recovery mode option at startup:

[image]

Any help with this issue?

Comment: did you change your partitions?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue might be that the /boot partition is full.
Please see if this suggestion by ager-wick at Ubuntu forums will help you: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1751574&p=12444063#post12444063